# How to determine first and last dates?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

**Background:**

I have snowpack records (expressed as [Snow Water Equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_science)) for the past 40+ years for numerous sites in the Pacific Northwest, USA. I need to determine the first and last dates that snow was on the ground for each water year (which extends from October 1 to September 30), for each site.

During the summer, the snowpack is (not surprisingly) zero.  As winter approaches, a date will occur when the first snowfall occurs; a non-zero value will then appear in the data for that date.  As winter progresses the snowpack increases to a maximum, then decreases throughout the spring back to zero.

I need to find the first and last dates where the snowpack value was non-zero, for all 40+ years, for all sites.

There is a separate Geopackage attribute table (containing all 40+ years of data) for each site, that looks like this:

> Water Year Date    Snowpack
> 1978   1978-10-01  0.0
> 1978   1978-10-02  0.1
> 1978   1978-10-03  0.0 *=> Here, all the snow melted; these are ignored*
> 1978   1978-10-04  0.1
> 1978   1978-10-05  0.2
> 1978   1978-10-06  0.4
> ...
> This continues through water year 2021

In the above example, the first date for water year 1978 would be 1978-10-02.

I have been determining these dates manually, by a series of filters and sorts.  However, this will become exhausting, so I'm looking for a way to automate.

**Question:**

For each water year, how do I determine the first and last dates that snow was recorded, without resorting to a manual method?

Bonus for also determining the date with the maximum snowpack value, along with that value!

Comment: This is a very simple summary statistics task. The only challenge is creating an integer attribute for individual hydrological year.

Answer (score 1):

First and last days in the year with snowpack value:

```
select x.theyear, x.mindate, max(sn.snowpack) as firstsnowval, y.maxdate, max(sx.snowpack) as lastsnowval
from (
    select theyear,  min(thedate)  as mindate
    from snows
    where snowpack > 0
    group by theyear )  x 
join (
    select theyear,  max(thedate)  as maxdate
    from snows
    where snowpack > 0
    group by theyear )  y on y.theyear = x.theyear
join snows sn on sn.thedate = x.mindate
join snows sx on sx.thedate = y.maxdate
group by x.theyear, x.mindate, y.maxdate
order by x.theyear
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS you can use virtual Layers with SQL for that. The SQL statement should be something like this one:

```
select max(Date) from your_table group by water_year having snowpack > 0
```

you should avoid column names with spaces if possible

[image]